# Text Field Unknown Props

Tags: reactjs, textfield, material-ui

I tried downloading one of the examples for Material UI and trying out the Text Field. The other components in the example worked just fine (e.g. Dialogue, Button). On TextField, defaultValue was the only prop I tried that worked. Thanks for help.

I keep getting the error:
Warning: Unknown props `hintText`, `floatingLabelText`, `floatingLabelFixed` on  tag.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField'
import withStyles from 'material-ui/styles/withStyles';
import withRoot from '../components/withRoot';

const styles = {
  root: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    paddingTop: 200,
  },
};

let hint = "I wish this would work.";

class Index extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField
            hintText={hint}
            floatingLabelText="Floating Label Text"
            floatingLabelFixed={true}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Index.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withRoot(withStyles(styles)(Index));
```

Comment: could you add the code for withRoot and withStyles HOCs as well

Comment: try to see what version of material ui you are using. their beta version has a different source code

Comment: I removed the withRoot and withStyles HOCs and it didn't affect the issue.

Comment: From the package.json for the Material UI node_module: "version": "1.0.0-beta.11" Maybe this is the issue - I'll try the not beta.

Comment: Swapped to stable version, everything works!

Answer (score 0):

This was using "version": "1.0.0-beta.11"

I switched to the lastest stable build, and everything works!

Comment: What version of material-ui have you been using?